# How can I change the style of clicked table row?

Tags: reactjs

I have more groups, which have more members of groups. So if the user click on one of the members, the style will change only of the element, that was clicked. Can you help me, how can I set a specific style of member?

```
{team.members !== undefined && team.members.length !== 0 ? team.members.map((mem, indexOfMember) => {
    return (
        <tbody key={indexOfMember}>
            {mem.member !== undefined && mem.member !== [] ?
                (
                    <tr onClick={() => swapMember(indexOfTeamModel,indexOfMember)}>
                        <td>{indexOfMember + 1}</td>
                        <td>{mem.member.nameOfPlayer !== undefined ? mem.member.nameOfPlayer : mem.member.name !== undefined ? mem.member.name : "..."}</td>
                        <td>{mem.member.surenameOfPlayer !== undefined ? mem.member.surenameOfPlayer : mem.member.surename !== undefined ? mem.member.name : "..."}</td>
                    </tr>
                ) : <p>Loading...</p>
            }

        </tbody>
    );
}) : <p>Loading ...</p>}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to store color state for all colorful `<tr>`.

```
const [colorState, setColorState] = React.useState({});
```

Then set style for `<tr>` like this:

```
<tr style={{background: `${colorState[`${indexOfTeamModel}-${indexOfMember}`] ? colorState[indexOfMember] : defaultColor}`}}></tr>
```

Write `onClick` function:

```
const onClickTr = (indexOfTeamModel, indexOfMember) => {
   const newColorState = {...colorState, [`${indexOfTeamModel}-${indexOfMember}`]: 'green' }; // change it to your color
   setColorState(newColorState);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solution is good, but now if I click on the first member in the first team, the green background is on all first members in other teams. Do you have any idea to solve it ?

Comment: @Ali, I fixed it, the key of state now unique and it's combine of team's index and member's index.

Comment: Thank you a lot, now it works :) I only must add  instead colorState[indexOfMember] : defaultColor -> colorState[`${indexOfTeamModel}-${indexOfMember}`] and it works